# What is the small sidearm of Imperial officers?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, blasters

In *Star Wars Rebels*, it appears that Imperial officers seem to have sidearm of some kind.
[image]

Can someone tell me what this sidearm is?

Comment: Can you recall which episode this is from, and who is wielding the pistol?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. The person wielding the pistol is Slavin, and the episode is "Hera's Heroes."

Comment: Dont think you will get a more definitive answer than it is "a standard Imperial blaster" issued to officers. There are no technical manuals out yet that are as fleshed out as those we had from the EU era.

Comment: I have asked this too on the Star Wars twitter page but have not received a response. My guess is that this sidearm has not received its own unique designation yet. It will in time I am sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tis an [RK-3](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/RK-3).

It was also featured in *Star Wars: Battlefront 2* (2017).

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Some additional information, possibly from your link, would do a lot to flesh out and improve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stinger Pistol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stinger_pistol)

Also known in Legends as Relby-K23 and unofficially as the Cloud City Pistol.

If you look at the following chart taken from the Wookieepedia article on [blaster pistols](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blaster_pistol/Legends), you can see that the Relby-K23 (column 1/row 5) is approximately the same.

[image: Labelled sketches of various Star Wars blaster pistols]

You can see both guns have a larger flaring tip and something sticking out of the bottom in front of the trigger.

Additionally this is the correct period for the Stinger Pistol to be in use.

> The stinger pistol was a model of blaster pistol used during the
> Galactic Civil War.
>
> [Stinger Pistol | Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stinger_pistol)

And the legends article says:

> The BlasTech Industries Relby-k23 blaster pistol was a sidearm banned
> from civilian purchase and used by agents of the Galactic Empire.
>
> [Relby-k23 blaster pistol | Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Relby-k23_blaster_pistol)

So allowing for deviation due to animation style and allowing Legends influence on Rebels, I'd identify this gun as a Stinger Pistol. Admittedly, it is very plausible that the show creators had no specific model in mind, and this is just another gun. One that will end up being classified at some point in the future by the next edition of *Star Wars: The Ultimate Visual Guide*.

Comment: I disagree. The muzzles are completely different, the barrel and receiver portions don't match, and the one OP is asking about has a much less sleek profile. Also, the cloud city blaster was silver, not matte black.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a definitive source, but looking through Wookieepedia it looks like it might be an [SC-4 Blaster pistol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SC-4_blaster_pistol).

Comment: Could be. A front view would be helpful. Is this Legends, though?

Comment: SoroSuub isn't part of Disney cannon.  Also the tip of the gun is different. The side is also distinctly different. deff not a SC-4

Comment: @Cherubel SoroSuub is cannon. Here it's mentioned on the official website for example: http://www.starwars.com/databank/comlink